# Why [Debug] button is replace by a [Morph] button in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos

In Xcode (3.2.4), `View` > `Layout` > `Show Page Control`.

In my old MacBook's Xcode, the Page Control shows `[Project]` and `[Debug]` buttons.
In my new MacBook, the Page Control shows `[Project]` and `[Morph]` buttons.

How can I get the old `[Debug]` button back and get rid of the `[Morph]` button? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close out any open projects.  `XCode Preferences` -> `General` tab -> `Layout` -> `All-In-One` instead of `Default` and you will have your `[Debug]` button back.

Cheers.